# Publish Multiple Custom Jars with Gradle

Tags: java, gradle, ant

I'm currently working on converting an Ant project over to Gradle and there are some build targets that output custom jars. I was curious if/how I'd go about this with Gradle? I know I can run Ant tasks from Gradle using `ant.importBuild`, but I'd like to run each task and publish the resulting jar+artifacts to a remote repository.

For example, I have these two Ant target builds:

```
<target name="build-client-jar" depends="compile-source"
            description="Builds the client application JAR.">
        <jar destfile="${build.dir}/${project.client.jar}"
                    compress="true"
                    index="true">
            <manifest>
                <attribute name="Class-Path"
                        value="${project.jar}"/>
                <attribute name="Built-By" value="${user.name}"/>
            </manifest>
            <fileset dir="${classes.dir}">
                <include name="com/example/project/client/**" />
                <include name="*.xml" />
            </fileset>
        </jar>
    </target>
```

and

```
<target name="build-model-jar" depends="compile-source"
            description="Builds the model application JAR.">
        <jar destfile="${build.dir}/Aps-Model.jar"
                    compress="true"
                    index="true">
            <manifest>
                <attribute name="Class-Path"
                        value="${project.jar}"/>
                <attribute name="Built-By" value="${user.name}"/>>
            </manifest>
            <fileset dir="${classes.dir}">
                <include name="com/example/project/model/**" />
            </fileset>
        </jar>
    </target>
```

Is it possible to run these same/similar tasks in Gradle and publish them to a remote repository?

Comment: Did the docs not help? https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/migrating_from_ant.html#migant:ivy_publishing

Comment: Not particularly. I understand how to publish a full library to a repo. It seems that if I want to build only parts of the project into different jars I need to reference custom tasks where the jar is the output. However, the documentation seems pretty slim on actual examples really only showing `println` in either a `doFirst` or `doLast`. How do I build the project, then package only specific classes from that build into a jar? How do I reference those custom artifacts in a `publications` block?

Answer (score 2):

I was able to figure it out but the docs weren't very clear on how to do this and required quite a bit of searching and stitching together various answers, but this is the solution I was able to come up with:

Tasks

```
task buildClientJar(type: Jar) {
    archiveAppendix.set("client")

    manifest {
        attributes("Class-Path": "Project-Client.jar")
        attributes(common, "common")
    }
    include(["com/project/path/client/**", "serviceBean.xml"])
    from configurations.runtimeClasspath.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    with jar
}

task buildModelJar(type: Jar) {
    archiveAppendix.set("model")

    manifest {
        attributes("Class-Path": "Project-Model.jar")
        attributes(common, "common")
    }
    include(["com/project/path/model/**"])
    from configurations.runtimeClasspath.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    with jar
}
```

Publishing

```
publishing {
    publications {
        client(MavenPublication) {
           artifact buildClientJar
           artifactId "Project-Client"
        }
        model(MavenPublication){
           artifact buildModelJar
           artifactId "Project-Model"
        }
    }
    repositories {[repo implementation]}
}
```

When building the jar Gradle will create the name with the following pattern: `[archiveBaseName]-[archiveAppendix]-[archiveVersion]-[archiveClassifier].[archiveExtension]`. In each task I used `archiveAppendix.set()` to make sure I got the proper jar name during the publication. Suppose I set `archivesBaseName = "Project"` and `version = '1.0.1'` in my `build.gradle`. The resulting jar from `buildClientJar` would be `Project-Client-1.0.1.jar`.

This gives me the packages I need as well as the Jars containing the appropriate files. The only downside to this is the `pom.xml` that is packaged with the jar contains no dependency information. So that will be my next task to figure out. Once that is done, I'll edit this response to contain the appropriate info.